# Как получить данные которые идут после # в адресной cтроке

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Вк при получение token'a с разрешением wall делает редирект на страницу типа

> index.php#access_token=469a...a229&expires_in=86400&user_id=12345678

Как получить в индекс данные после #, и вообще что это за метод такой.. почему не "?" ?

Comment: вы наверное смотрите авторизация для standalone, а надо для сервера

Comment: @АлексейШиманский для использования polls.create требуется через standalone получить ключ... так написано.. я в тупике

Comment: А вы знаете что такое standalone? это точно не php

Comment: @АлексейШиманский знаю что точно не php, не знаю как polls.create из под php пользовать, не подскажете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    // отправляете полученное AJAX запросом на сервер
}
```

Тут нужно понимать что если вы используете клиентский `access_token` для доступа к API от сер­ве­ра, то вы что-то делаете не так. Скорее всего на той стороне есть до­по­лнительные про­верки на ку­ки клиента, который получал этот ключ, которые сделают желаемое вами исполь­зование невозможные. Если нет, считайте, повезло.